# OpenEMM Installation

Tags: windows

Guys, I have installed `OpenEMM 2013` on Windows 2012 Server. Everything works fine as per installation guide but when I am trying to start the `OpenEMM` using `start.bat`, I am facing some problem.

It says's -

> Starting up .. home is C:\OpenEMM .. found codebase .. warning: no MySQL found using reg.key SOFTWARE\MySQL AB, continue anyway found database.
>   Running, press return for termination:

Also I have found the log file in the `/var/log/openemm_stderr.log`

> SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.

I have opened the port - 8005,8009,8443,8080 in my Firewall. But still I can not start `openemm service`.

Comment: Firewall does not come into play if you are testing locally on the machine. When you say everything works fine, what do you mean? Also what is the code in the **start.bat** file

Comment: Which version of OpenEMM did you download: 2013 or 2013 R2 ?